# Disable Auto Shipping Update in Magento Admin

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

If you've used the Magento admin, then you know that when you tab between the "Shipping Address" order screen it's kind of buggy.  It does an AJAX call behind the scenes anytime that any field is updated.  This keeps the shipping up to date, but its very annoying when trying to key in orders.  Does anyone know a good way to disable this automatic functionality, so that it could be done with a button, instead of happen "automagically"?

Answer (score -1):

I can't point to anything specific at the code level, as I don't have the code handy to look at just now, but I know it won't be easy per-se.

You will need to find and rewrite (unless it's all in the templates, then you'll need a custom admin theme) the block which generates that form, strip out the calls which add the handlers to the `onblur` events. Theoretically, your button should be able to call the same JavaScript method which is called via the `onblur` of the form elements.

Comment: P.S. There is a [Magento site proposal on Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48872/magento?referrer=OO7r6fZfer327y6ehRWkiw2) to have a Q&A site dedicated to handling Magento specific questions and better serve the community. We are getting super close to beta, only need 7 more committed individuals with 200+ rep on another SE networked site. We would appreciate your support! :)

Comment: I've been at a complete loss at identifying where the event attaches to the form fields. Even looking at it with "inspect element" doesn't shed a lot of light on what event is being called and what is triggering it.  I agree with what you said in principal, but do you know of any other details for this particular puzzel.